# Bash Scripting checking for home directories

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I'm trying to create a script to check if user accounts have valid home directories.

This is what i got at the moment:

```
#!/bin/bash

cat /etc/passwd | awk -F: '{print $1 " " $3 " " $6 }' | while read user userid directory; do
if [ $userid -ge 1000 ] && [ ! -d "$directory ]; then
echo ${user}
fi
done
```

This works. I get the expected output which is the username of the account with an invalid home directory.

eg. output

```
student1
student2
```

However, I am unable to make it so that ONLY if there is no issues with the valid home directories and all of them are valid, echo "All home directories are valid".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set a flag, and unset it if you see an invalid directory. Or you could simply check whether your loop printed anything.

You have a number of common antipatterns which you'll want to avoid, too.

```
# Avoid useless use of cat
# If you are using Awk anyway,
# use it for user id comparison, too
awk -F: '$3 >= 1000 {print $1, $6 }' /etc/passwd |
# Basically always use read -r
while read -r user directory; do
    # Fix missing close quote
    if [ ! -d "$directory" ]; then
        # Quote user
        echo "$user"
    fi
done |
# If no output, print default message
grep '^' >&2 || echo "No invalid directories" >&2
```

A proper tool prints its diagnostic output to standard error, not standard output, so I added `>&2` to the end.

Comment: can you further explain
grep '^' >&2 || echo "No invalid directories" >&2

like grep '^' and >&2... am i right to say grep '^' checks whether if there is output from the if statement and >&2 outputs a standard error

Comment: Yes exactly, and the `||` "or" says if grep failed to find any matches, do the `echo` as well. `if this; then that; else something; fi` can be expressed in shorthand `this && that || something` where each command can be an arbitrarily complex compound command; only we tend to prefer the longhand `if; then; else; fi` for legibility when the commande are nontrivial.

Answer (score 1):

Didn't run it, but it should be something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

users=()
cat /etc/passwd | awk -F: '{print $1 " " $3 " " $6 }' | while read user userid directory; do
if [ $userid -ge 1000 ] && [ ! -d "$directory" ]; then
  users=+("${user}")
fi
done

if test -n ${#users[@]} == 0; then
  echo "All home directories are valid"
else
  for (( i=0; i<${#users[@]}; i++ )); do echo "${users[$i]}" ; done
fi
```